# C# equivalent to AS3 Vector?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

Is there an equivalent object type for Actionscript's Vector in C#? If not, what is would generally be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [ActionScript® 3.0 Reference for the Adobe® Flash® Platform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html):

> The Vector class lets you access and manipulate a vector — an array whose elements all have the same data type.

The equivalent class in .NET is the generic [List<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

> Represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by index.

The element's type is designated by the generic type parameter `T`. So, for example, a "Vector with base type String" `Vector.<String>` in Flash would be a "List of X" `List<string>` in C#.

*Example:*

```
var dinosaurs = new List<string>();

dinosaurs.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");

foreach (var dinosaur in dinosaurs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) in .NET.